# What is the solution of normalized harmonic series based on $4/3$ between one and two?

Tags: power-series, harmonic-functions, harmonic-numbers, music-theory

In music theory notes generated by the consequencing interval of $4/3$ generates harmonic series. Series can be normalized by multiplicating the fraction with a $2$ in power $n$.

What is a formula for $n$ depending on $m$ such that the ratio is always between $1$ and $2$?

I'm looking for integer solutions for n when m is a whole number:

$$1 \le (4/3)^m * 2^n \le 2$$

Comment: Are $m$ and $n$ positive?

Comment: m and n can be either positive or negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take logarithms on both sides:

$$
0\le m\log\frac43+n\log2\le\log2\;.
$$

This is an area in the $(m,n)$ plane that lies between two parallel lines. Solving for $n$ yields

$$
-m\log_2\frac43\le n\le1-m\log_2\frac43\;,
$$

so

$$
n=\left\lceil-m\log_2\frac43\right\rceil\approx\left\lceil-0.415m\right\rceil\;,
$$

where $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ is the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: Would you mind to see the follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899922/is-there-an-arithmetic-mean-limit-on-the-symmetrical-items-of-the-harmonic-serie

Answer (score 1):

The inequality can be rewritten as
$$
\Bigl(\frac{3}{4}\Bigr)^m\le 2^n\le2\,\Bigl(\frac{3}{4}\Bigr)^m.
$$
Taging logarithms an dividing by $\log2>0$, we get
$$
\frac{\log(3/4)}{\log2}\,m\le n\le1+\frac{\log(3/4)}{\log2}\,m.
$$
From here, it follows that
$$
n=\Bigl\lfloor\frac{\log(3/4)}{\log2}\,m\Bigr\rfloor,
$$
where $\lfloor\ \rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: I think you need the ceiling function instead of the floor function.

Comment: Right. Floor gives normalization between 0 and 1, but ceil between 1 and 2.

Comment: @MarkokraM: I think you mean between $\frac12$ and $1$?

Comment: @joriki To be more precise, yes, floor seems to normalize series between half and one.